# symfony2 doctrine count number of joined entity

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have Article and Category Entity with manyToOne relation. I want to list categories with number of article in it. How can I query for it With Doctrine2 **efficiently**?

Comment: Is article entity points category entity in `manyToOne` way or category entity points article entity  in `manyToOne` way ? can  you show your both entities ?

Comment: one category can have many article related to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set your category entity properly then you can get its article collection by just calling its getter count, suppose you have entities mapped as below

Article

```
class Article
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $category;
    // ... title ,id ,bla bla bla
}
```

Category

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Category
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $articles;
    // ... title ,id ,bla bla bla    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->articles= new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Then you can just loop your category entity in controller

```
$DM = $this->getContainer()->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$categories = $DM->getRepository('Namespace\YourBundle\Entity\Category')->findAll();
foreach($categories as $c){
echo $this->getTitle();
echo count($this->getArticles());
}
```

In twig

```
{% for c in categories %}
{{ c.getTitle() }}
{{ c.getArticles()|length }}
{% endfor %}
```

Through query builder you can do so

```
$DM = $this->getContainer()->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$query = $DM->createQueryBuilder()
      ->select('c.id,c.title, COUNT(a.id) as article_count')
      ->from('NamespaceYourBunle:Category', 'c')
      ->innerJoin('c.articles', 'a')
      ->groupBy('c.id')
;
$categories= $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```